# OpenCart template design strategy

Tags: opencart

I have read about opencart template system but it is still too vague for me. My question is that:

Should built opencart templates from scratch (like wordpress) or I have to make a copy of default template and start editing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually depends, i have created many themes by copying the default but this approach will only get you so far.
To better explain i will specify 2 cases.

1. If you wish to make a responsive design with many new features a new theme from scratch may be more appropriate, but this is only the case where those functionalities are modules not display changes.
2. In the second case when you have to do a mosttly visual change then you should take the default theme or one more relative to what you desire and change it afterwards.

Till now i have had only once to create a theme from scratch, cause i wanted it to be like etsy. All other cases were based on other template files like the default and some css js and html changes, i almost always get a new theme in one hour with the second approach. While in the first case it took me one month :-).

Hope i helped you with my answer.